# I am using cursor with a dynamic sql but when using further with bulk binding results are not coming

Tags: oracle, plsql

With PL/SQL oracle, I am using cursor with a dynamic sql but when using further with bulk binding results are not coming, but when using without bulk binding it works. Please suggest what am i missing here, sample below is a code snippet for your reference, although it is not the exact code but will give you an overview what i am trying to do.

```
cur_data SYS_REFCURSOR;
TYPE sample_data IS RECORD
  (
      col1      VSAMPLEDATA.COL1%TYPE,
      col2      VSAMPLEDATA.COL2%TYPE

  );

TYPE reclist IS TABLE OF sample_data ;
rec reclist;

Begin
p_query_string:='SELECT * from  VSAMPLEDATA where COL2=:pVal';

OPEN cur_data FOR p_query_string USING 'DATA1';
    LOOP
    FETCH cur_data 
            BULK COLLECT INTO rec LIMIT 1000;
    EXIT WHEN 
            rec.COUNT = 0;
            FOR indx IN 1 .. rec.COUNT
            LOOP
                doing something;
            END LOOP
    END LOOP
    CLOSE cur_data ;
```

Comment: Why do you need dynamic SQL?

Comment: I'm with Aleksej; there's no need for dynamic sql here, assuming your example code accurately reflects your actual code. Also, depending on what your "doing something" is, it's possible you don't need to loop through a cursor at all - e.g. if you're inserting / updating / deleting.

Comment: i need dynamic sql here, as there will be some conditions i need to add on to the query based upon some calculations. This is not the exact code as it was too big to write here.

Comment: I believe you will only need dynamic SQL if you have to change the tables you select from; if you only need to change the WHERE condition, this can quite always be done with some boolean logic, without dynamic SQL

Comment: yes Aleksej need to add tables as well thats why we are using dynamic sql.

Comment: If you could include a [simplified test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the issue (with and without bulk binding) that would be helpful. At the moment looking at your mock code I can't see why you would not get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `sys_refcursor` in wrong way.Also there is no need to use cursor in your case. `sys_refcursor` can be used to pass cursors from and to a stored procedure. `SYS_REFCURSOR` is a pre-declared weak ref cursor.

Also you are not `executing` the `query` so `no result` when using a bind variable. `Execute Immediate` is missing while using a binding the variable.  See below example:

```
declare

TYPE sample_data IS RECORD
  (
      col1        EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID%type,
      col2        EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME%type    
  );

TYPE reclist IS TABLE OF sample_data;

rec reclist;

p_query_string varchar2(1000);

BEGIN
   p_query_string := 'SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME from  EMPLOYEE where EMPLOYEE_ID=:pVal';

   Execute immediate p_query_string BULK COLLECT INTO rec USING 1;

  FOR indx IN 1 .. rec.COUNT
    LOOP
         --doing something;
         dbms_output.put_line(rec(indx).col1);
    END LOOP;

End;
```

Comment: here Execute immediate dont use limit clause, Do you think that this can cause any memory related problem, because i have read many times bulk collection to be used with LIMIT clause just to avoid memory outage.

Comment: As per oracle doc http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#CJACGJJG there is no construct to use Limit cluase in `Execute Immediate`. There are risk of memory outage but you would had to run it and test it incase you want it dynamically. Or you can put some condition in select statement to restrict rows and then run that in loop , that may solve your problem. But before arriving on any point you need to really test it.

Comment: That would be risky on production anyway thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well anything tried directly in Prod would be risky. You would need to check with the same load of data in development first. Also check how many record you actually have. If the number is not huge then you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid dynamic SQL and build a simpler, safer parametric cursor; for example, reflecting the structure of your code:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE sample_data IS RECORD(col1 VSAMPLEDATA.COL1%TYPE, col2 VSAMPLEDATA.COL2%TYPE);
    TYPE reclist IS TABLE OF sample_data;
    --
    rec                                     reclist;
    --
    CURSOR cur_data(param IN VARCHAR2) IS
        SELECT *
          FROM VSAMPLEDATA
         WHERE COL2 = param;
BEGIN
    OPEN cur_data('DATA1');

    LOOP
        FETCH cur_data BULK COLLECT INTO rec LIMIT 1000;

        EXIT WHEN rec.COUNT = 0;

        FOR indx IN 1 .. rec.COUNT
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(rec(indx).col1 || ' - ' || rec(indx).col2);
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur_data;
END;
```

**Test case:**

```
create table VSAMPLEDATA(col1, col2) as 
    select 1, 'DATA1' from dual union all
    select 2, 'DATA2' from dual
```

The result:

```
1 - DATA1
```

Comment: i need dynamic sql here, as there will be some conditions i need to add on to the query based upon some calculations. This is not the exact code as it was too big to write here

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone this one has been resolved. It was always working, only problem was with the underlying query which had some conditional checks due to that results were not coming.